# WebSVN does not show repositories

Tags: php, apache, svn, websvn

I am migrating a svn server from CentOS 5 to a CentOS 7 Server.
What I did is very simple.

I have installed subversion and websvn with yum package manager.
I have followed following document to create svn dumps and to set up svn on CentOS 7: 
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-setup-an-apache-subversion-svn-server-on-centos-7

I configured config.php to point to /home/svn like so:

```
$config->parentPath('/home/svn')
```

I then configured a virtualhost for apache like so:

```
<Location /home/svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /home/svn
        SVNListParentPath on
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/svn-acl-conf
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        # - Removed from Apache 2.4 and beyond
        #AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
        AuthLDAPUrl <LDAPServer>cn=users,dc=<LDAPServer>,dc=rinis,dc=nl?uid
        AuthName "SVN: Login met je gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord"
        Require valid-user
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subversion.<domain>.nl
        ServerAdmin admin@<domain>.nl
        ServerName subversion.<domain>.nl
        ServerSignature email
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php
        ErrorLog        /var/log/httpd/subversion-error.log
        CustomLog       /var/log/httpd/subversion-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

WebSVN is showing up, I have imported one repository to check if it's working, but the repository does not show.

I can't see what I am missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by granting correct (apache) rights to the repository directories.